# Como chamo uma corotina assíncrona dentro de uma função que está inicializada em uma thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telepot, time, threading, asyncio
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from datetime import datetime
from telepot.namedtuple import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel
...
all_participants = []
pts_organ = {}
...
client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token = bot_token)

def getMembros(canal_id):
    global all_participants, pts_organ
    ...
    all_participants =  client.get_participants(PeerChannel(canal_id), aggressive=True)
    ...
    return pts_organ

...
def handle(msg):
     ...
     else:
        if (msg[content_type] == '/todos_os_membros'):
            getMembros(chat_id)

MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
```

Quando executo o script, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 37, in run_forever
    self._handle(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\Desktop\bot.py", line 103, in handle
    getMembros(chat_id)
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\Desktop\bot.py", line 26, in getMembros
    all_participants =  client.get_participants(PeerChannel(canal_id), aggressive=True)
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 35, in syncified
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 39
    traceback.print_exc()
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ChatMethods.get_participants' was never awaited
```

Só quero que o meu método `getMembros(canal_id)` retorne a lista de membros de um canal, mas parece que não estou conseguindo pelo fato de que o método `get_participants()` da *API Telethon* é assíncrono. Não sei ao certo. Não entendo muita coisa sobre o módulo *asyncio* e *Thread*.

Já tentei:

```
 ...
 async def getMembros(canal_id):
      ...
      all_participants =  await client.get_participants(PeerChannel(canal_id), aggressive=True)
```

O erro:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\Desktop\bot.py", line 103
    getMembros(chat_id)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'getMembros' was never awaited
```

Depois:

```
 ...
 async def handle(msg):
    ...
    await getMembros(chat_id)
```

E o seguinte erro:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 37
    self._handle(msg)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'handle' was never awaited
```

Não sei o que fazer mais. Sei que `client.get_participants()` leva um tempo pra terminar, então queria saber como posso deixá-lo em paralelo, pra que `handle(msg)` continue sendo executado ou algo do tipo. Ou encontrar uma forma de conseguir retornar o dicionário `pts_organ`, do `getMembros`, que está responsável por retorná-lo,  dentro do `handle(msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral *ou* você usa código assíncrono para coisas em paralelo, *ou* usa código em múltiplas threads. Dá para misturar os dois - e é comum ter tarefas demoradas rodando em outras threads, e você controla isso a partir do código assincrono.

O fato é que uma função que é declarada com `async def`, quando é chamada, não é executada. Só quando você executa `await` no item que é retornado de uma função dessas é que ela é de fato executada. (por isso o "warning": não é que deu erro - mas você preparou todo o ambiente para executar o código em uma certa função, e nunca chamou aquele código, que então não foi executado. O que chama o código é a expressão `await`)

Só que aí que entra outra pegadinha: você não pode simplesmente usa `await` em uma função normal, que não é criada com `async def`.

Se seu código está paralelizado usando threads, e não async, e você quer só chamar essa função, uma forma de fazer é iniciar e fechar o loop fazendo só essa chamada.
Um loop do asyncio iniciado em uma thread vai ficar restrito àquela thread.

Resumindo, uma forma simples de chamar seu `client.get_participants` é pdir para o asyncio inicializar um novo loop, executar até o fim, e fechar o loop com a chamada `asyncio.run`:

```
all_participants =  asyncio.run(client.get_participants(PeerChannel(canal_id), aggressive=True))
```

- a chamada `asyncio.run`, nova no Python 3.7, ao contrário de `loop.run_until_complete` da versão 3.4, cria um novo loop de eventos automaticamente mesmo se não estiver na thread principal, espera a conclusão da co-rotina passada como parâmetro, e retorna seu resultado. Num design normal, ela seria o ponto de entrada das rotinas declaradas com `async def` - e seria chamada uma única vez.

*Pode ser* que você ainda tenha problemas, já que a biblioteca está desenhada para um paralelismo com async, e você está forçando um modelo de threads em cima. Se os problemas persisitrem, melhor re-escrever todo o seu código para usar asyncio (e aí você não precisa mais de threads)